# Making my Blogger blog responsive: how to get the sizes right for all mobile devices

Tags: blogger

For my blog www.lemontierres.com I have been trying to make the mobile design right for all devices, but my blog doesn't seem to work properly on an iPhone 6 and an iPhone 6+. I don't know how to fix this.

I can't post images because I don't have 10 reputation yet but the main images on the landing page don't center on my blog for the iPhone 6+ view. How can I change this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` meta tag

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How can I do that? I kind of figured out how to adjust HTML codes but I don't know how to add a meta tag.

Comment: Hm, I just saw that you already have this in your code. It should work. I am not familiar with Blogger.

Comment: No problem, thanks for trying to help me though. Still doesn't work, think I've done something wrong but I will try to fix it :-)